# Select canvas item using mouseclick and delete particular Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Ellipses on wpf canvas I want to select ellipses multiple and delete particular

selected Ellipse how to achieve using `List<Ellipse>`

I have code for Delete Logic.

```
if (SelectedCanvasItem.VisualHit.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Shape))
{
    var SelectedShapeTag = SelectedCanvasItem.VisualHit.GetValue(Shape.TagProperty);
    if (SelectedCanvasItem != null)
    {
        //Ellipse SelectedHole = (Ellipse)SelectedShapeTag;
        grdGrid.Children.Remove(SelectedCanvasItem.VisualHit as Shape);
        //SetActivePattern(SelectedHole.ParentPattern);
        //SelectedHoleSelectedHole.ParentPattern.CurrentHole = SelectedHole;
        return; //Get out, we're done.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i uderstood you correctly, then:

1) You should write VisualStates to selected and unselected items - to let user understand that those elipses are selected.
2) On selection you can create a list of elipses List ToDelete and whe user is ready - delete them

If you want to achieve it only in XAML i think its not achievable.

But if you want to delete 1 by 1 than you can add Behavior to each ellipse - delete from form or something like that.

C#:

```
List<string> Deletable_elipses

Elipse_Tap()
{
Elipse tappedElipse = sender as Elipse;
if (Deletable_elipses.Contains(tappedElipse.Name))
{
    List.Remove(tappedElipse.Name); //Add if not in list to delete means that user unselected it
}
else
{
    List.Add(tappedElipse.Name); //Add if not in list to delete means that user selected it
}
```

}

And when you want to delete elipses:

```
foreach (string name in Deletable_elipses)
{
    Elipse current = (Elipse)this.FindName(name);
    current. //TODO logic to delete
}
```

Comment: i have code for delete logic .but i want how to select particular Ellipse in WPF

Comment: How about making a list of names something like:

Comment: i have added ellipses how to retrieve ellipses   _tubeHoles.Add(new Circle(new Point3D(100, 0, 0), tubeOD))